# Сложный список angular

Tags: angularjs

Есть массив типа =

```
[
{"name":"Name","dep":"Dep1"},
{"name":"Name","dep":"Dep1"},
{"name":"Name","dep":"Dep1"},
{"name":"Name","dep":"Dep2"},
{"name":"Name","dep":"Dep3"},
]
```

Вопрос вот в чем. Как его правильно вывести с помощью ng-repeat или чего другого если нужно каждый новый отдел в списке отделять разделителем?

Примерно так:

```
<div class="delimiter">Dep1</div>
<div>Name</div>
<div>Name</div>
<div>Name</div>
<div class="delimiter">Dep2</div>
<div>Name</div>
<div>Name</div>
```

Comment: Напишите итоговый HTML, который хотите получить. По словесному описанию непонятно.

Comment: <div class="delimiter">Dep1</div>
<div>Name</div>
<div>Name</div>
<div>Name</div>
<div class="delimiter">Dep2</div>
<div>Name</div>
<div>Name</div>

Comment: @Fenex, понятно всё.

Comment: @ВарфаламейИзольдин, а Dep3 почему нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function Controller($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {"name":"Name","dep":"Dep1"},
    {"name":"Name","dep":"Dep1"},
    {"name":"Name","dep":"Dep1"},
    {"name":"Name","dep":"Dep2"},
    {"name":"Name","dep":"Dep3"}
  ];
}
```

```css
.is-other {
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

.is-other:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<script src=//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js></script>

<ul ng-app ng-controller=Controller>
  <li ng-repeat="item in data" ng-class="{'is-other': item.dep!==data[$index-1].dep}">{{item.dep}} -> {{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

```js
function Controller($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {"name":"Name","dep":"Dep1"},
    {"name":"Name","dep":"Dep1"},
    {"name":"Name","dep":"Dep1"},
    {"name":"Name","dep":"Dep2"},
    {"name":"Name","dep":"Dep3"}
  ];
}
```

```css
.dep {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src=//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller=Controller>
  <div ng-repeat="item in data">
    <div ng-if="item.dep!==data[$index-1].dep" class=dep>{{item.dep}}</div>
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Над первым ничего нет. И над разделителем название Dep хотелось бы.

Comment: @ВарфаламейИзольдин, над первым я специально убрал. Зачем ему одинокая разделительная линия? Название без проблем присобачивается css'ом.

Comment: @ВарфаламейИзольдин, добавил ещё вариант. Но вообще-то надо бы структуру объекта менять, чтобы нормально сделать.

Comment: А как поменять?

Comment: @ВарфаламейИзольдин, что именно поменять? о_О

Comment: " Но вообще-то надо бы структуру объекта менять, чтобы нормально сделать. –  Qwertiy" -  так я и спросил как поменять?

Comment: @ВарфаламейИзольдин, `[{dep:"dep1",services:[{name:"Name1"},{name:"Name2"}]}, {dep:"dep2",services:[{name:"Name1"}]}]`

Comment: Так и думал. Спасибо. Сейчас освобожусь попробую ваш способ.

Comment: Qwertiy, я тут вернул ваше авторское форматирование в одну строку. Но автоформатирование в сниппете предлагает всё разнести по строкам, как было у предыдущего редактора.

Comment: @sashatexb, и чем тебе запятые не угодили?

Comment: @Qwertiy я ЗА правильный и чистый код!

Comment: @sashatexb, так с запятыми он и есть чистый.